# How do "Dock leaves" work to reduce itching from stinging nettles?

Tags: plants

[Dock leaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumex) are the wild cure to stinging nettles, right? Everyone knows this.

But how do they stop the stinging? What's the mechanism?

Comment: Someone answered this one in another SE site: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/does-rubbing-a-dock-leaf-on-a-sting-from-a-stinging-nettle-help-to-reduce-pain

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been answered on skeptics: [Does rubbing a dock leaf on a sting from a stinging nettle help to reduce pain?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/does-rubbing-a-dock-leaf-on-a-sting-from-a-stinging-nettle-help-to-reduce-pain)

Comment: Just because something is on-topic and even answered on another SE site does not preclude users from asking a similar question on this SE site. See [this somewhat relevant SE blog post](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/). An individual user cross-posting identical questions is strongly discouraged, but similar questions which appear naturally on multiple sites are not a problem.

Comment: Perhaps the best approach to this then is to answer the question referencing the other on Skeptics and quote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered at https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/does-rubbing-a-dock-leaf-on-a-sting-from-a-stinging-nettle-help-to-reduce-pain

For posterity I will recreate the answer

> This is from a forum post so it could use a bit more of a hard
>   reference, but it contains some useful and verifiable info:
>
> It is said that nettle stings are caused by the formic acid in the
>   sting solution. If it were true, then Dock leaves, which contain
>   Oxalic acid, would not be a remedy. The extremely fine syringe type
>   hair of the Nettle breaks off easily and penetrates the skin. Within
>   this hair is a stinging solution which is only 1% Formic acid. A 2% -
>   10% concentration is required for the acid to be an irritant. It is
>   histamine and serotonin in the sting which cause the irritation.
>
> Dock leaf sap contains a natural antihistamine. If you rub too hard
>   with the dock leaf, you will merely disturb the nettle sting in your
>   skin and make it worse. The best way to deal with the problem is to
>   break off some dock leaf and chew it for a few seconds, then gently
>   rub the saliva/dock sap mixture around the sting. The antihistamine
>   from the dock leaf together with the natural healing properties of
>   saliva will ease the stinging sensation.